# how to validate fingerprints in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, fingerprint, biometrics

I am working on an Angular web application that uses the DigitalPersona 4500 fingerprint reader device u are u. The application aims to register fingerprints and store them in a database for later comparison to grant access.

Currently I already have the fingerprint registration and storage, I am storing the fingerprint in my database as binaries:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4PQT.png)

Given that the application is entirely web-based and nothing is stored locally, I'm seeking guidance on how to validate fingerprints within this environment. Any insights or suggestions on suitable approaches or tools for fingerprint validation in a web context would be greatly appreciated.